# Autoencoder for Extremely Sparse Data

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, sparse

I am attempting to train an autoencoder on data that is extremely sparse.  Each datapoint is only zeros and ones and contains ~3% 1s.  Being that the data is mostly zero the autoencoder learns to guess zero every time.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  To give context this is extremely sparse data when you consider that the number of features is over 865,000

Comment: while this is not a solution to your question, but a comment. Look for autoencoders used in building recommender systems. Recommender systems often use very sparse data (99.9% sparsity) as a tiny portion of the movies offered by netflix are of interest to a particular person. Neflix enginnering blogs could be a possible place.